# Confidence interval for the restricted mean in survival analysis

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival, stata, mean

What is the recommended way of calculating confidence intervals for the *restricted mean* in survival analysis? Here are some example data, taken from the paper

Chris Barker (2009), [The Mean, Median, and Confidence Intervals of the Kaplan–Meier Survival Estimate—Computations and Applications](http://dx.doi.org/10.1198/tast.2009.0015), The American Statistician, Volume 63, Issue 1, 2009.

Note that, despite the title, the paper does *not* list any confidence intervals for the mean. R (3.0.2) can calculate an *estimate* of the restricted mean, but only calculates a confidence interval for the median, not for the mean:

```
> library(survival)
> time = c(10, 15, 23, 30, 35, 52, 100)
> dead = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
> fit = survfit(Surv(time, dead) ~ 1)
> print(fit, print.rmean=TRUE)
Call: survfit(formula = Surv(time, dead) ~ 1)

records      n.max    n.start     events     *rmean *se(rmean)     median    0.95LCL    0.95UCL 
7.0        7.0        7.0        6.0       37.9       10.7       30.0       15.0         NA 
* restricted mean with upper limit =  100
```

(Here the restricted mean is estimated to be 37.9, based on a cutoff of 100.) Stata (13.0), on the other hand, happily calculates a confidence interval:

```
|    no. of  restricted
|  subjects        mean      Std. Err.    [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
  total |         7    37.85714(*)   10.73888      16.8093     58.905

(*) largest observed analysis time is censored, mean is underestimated
```

This seems to be based on a normal approximation, i.e., estimated mean ± 1.96 standard errors. In R, one can calculate this more or less manually, using numbers extracted from the fit:

```
fit.table = summary(fit, rmean=TRUE)$table # or, preferably, rmean=100
rmean = fit.table[["*rmean"]]                               # Estimate restricted mean
rmean.se = fit.table[["*se(rmean)"]]                        # Estimated standard error
rmean + c(-1,1) * qnorm(.05/2, lower.tail=FALSE) * rmean.se # 95% CI
[1] 16.80932 58.90497
```

Is this a good way of calculating confidence intervals for restricted means (at least if the cutoff for the restricted mean is fixed in advance)? Or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Vignette for `survRM2` package: illustrates how to use the functions in the
package to compare two groups with respect to the restricted mean survival time.

Comment: For me it is still a relevant question. If you have any more insights by now, I would love to hear them!